# Configure privacy settings via the command line

Tags: command-line, system-settings, privacy, configure

I am trying to compile a script to run upon booting a network attached computer (which has no hard drive and therefore is a new computer upon every reboot) to configure all settings. Because it will be run during startup.

I need to find ways to turn off the "record activity" and/or "send reports" functions just using the command line?